# Wrong output of reference to pointer to int

Tags: c++

I am trying to use a reference to pointer to `int` like in below program. But I am not getting the expected output.

Output:

```
9 5
5 9
```

Expecting:

```
9 5
9 5
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap (int *& a, int *&b)
{
    int *t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5, b = 9;       
    int *p = &a;
    int *q = &b;

    swap (p, q);
    cout << *p << " " << *q << endl;
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Why is my expectation wrong? I head that reference is nothing just an other name of the target variable.

Answer (score 2):

You swap the pointers, not the values. Your expectation is wrong.

Comment: Additionally, OP should try to understand **why** references or pointers required to swap two objects, and he should not assume only "well that's needed because I saw it on SO", etc.

Answer (score 1):

You're swapping the values of the pointers.

Look at this illustration:

First, `p` is pointing at `a`, `q` is pointing at `b`:

```
  p         a
+---+     +---+
+ ------> | 5 |
+---+     +---+

  q         b
+---+     +---+
+ ------> | 9 |
+---+     +---+
```

After you swap `p` and `q`, `q` is pointing at `a`, and `p` is pointing at `b`:

```
  q         a
+---+     +---+
+ ------> | 5 |
+---+     +---+

  p         b
+---+     +---+
+ ------> | 9 |
+---+     +---+
```

But both `a` and `b` still have their old values.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you are swapping two pointers and not what they point to.

Maybe your function is confusing you as you are calling the values a and b. Your function swaps two pointers such that the first one now points where the second one was pointing, and the second points to where the first was pointing.

`p` was previously pointing to `a` and `q` to `b`. Now `p` points to `b` and `q` points to `a` thus your output is 9 5 5 9

There are references in your `swap` function. These are references to the pointers, so `a` and `b` in the function scope become aliases to the parameters passed in, i.e. `p` and `q` and thus modify `p` and `q` (to point elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you're swapping the pointers (and not the values). Since you're swapping the pointers, the actual *values* inside `a` and `b` remain unchanged. Hencewhy when you print the value of `a`, you get `5` and when you print `b` you get `9`.

Answer (score 0):

> I head that reference is nothing just a other name of the target
>   variable

Yes, and *target variable* in your case is a pointer of the variable, not the variable. Because you're using `*` in the function declaration. Then, you're swaping pointers not values.

Use one of these ways:

```
void swap(int &a, int &b)
{
    int t=a;
    a=b;
    b=t;
}
// ...

int a=5,b=9;        
swap(a,b);
```

or

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int t=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=t;
}
// ...

int a=5,b=9;        
swap(&a,&b);
```